# Error An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework

Basicamente me esta saliendo este error al intentar guardar cambios cuando hago un update a una clase

Este es el controlador uwu

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

        public IActionResult Editar(TblFuncionario funcionario)
        {
            if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                 _context.Update(funcionario);
                 _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View();
        }
```

pruebas del ERROR UWU

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

Error

SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan value)

DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection)

Cuando pongos los puntos de depuración, el erro se me salta en el   _context.SaveChanges();

Comment: Muestra siempre código, salidas y mensajes de error _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Comment: La fecha está mal ahí lo pone clarito

Comment: Como indica el error _"SqlTypeException: SqlDateTime overflow"_ la fecha que envias en un campo del objeto "funcionario" no esta en el rango del tipo de dato [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) del SQL  Server. ¿Puedes colocar los valores del objeto "funcionario" (mas las propiedes fechas que tienes?  Por eso los valores si puedes colocar. Otra es cambiar el tipo en la DB por [DateTime2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)